# Spark: Json with schema returns Null

Tags: apache-spark-sql

The below spark code returns null value on read:

Json Data:

```
 {
      "TITLE" : "FLIGHT AND IATA LIST",
      "AIRLINES":
    [
      {
        "IATA_CODE" :"UA",
        "AIRLINE": "United Air Lines Inc."
      },
      {
        "IATA_CODE" :"AA",
        "AIRLINE": "American Airlines Inc."
      }
  ]
    }
```

Schema:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

object Airlines {

  val airlines_fields = Array(
    StructField("Title",StringType,false),
    StructField("Airlines",ArrayType(
      StructType(Array(
      StructField("IATA_CODE",StringType,false),
      StructField("AIRLINE",StringType,false)
      ))
    ),false)
  )

  val schema = StructType(airlines_fields)
}
```

Spark code:

```
spark.read.schema(Airlines.schema).json("src/main/resources/airlines.json").show()
```

I tried without specifying schema, it throw'ed me an error, so created schema but this time returns null value.

Comment: Which exception did it throw?

Comment: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException

Comment: Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed

Comment: If I read the schema without explicitly specifying the schema, it display - Structype(StructField(_corrupt_record, StringType, true))

Comment: I assume you're using Spark 2.3 or higher. Is that right?

Comment: yes, its Spark 2.3

Comment: Try adding this: spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json(...)